# Playing audio files with Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I'm developing an app in React and Redux. I have a timer thunk which dispatches an action every second and the state is updated to represent the actual time. Now this is great for the UI but I need to play a sound at specific times and I'm not sure where this logic should go.

I could modify the timer thunk to play the sound but this doesn't seem a good solution to me as I think the timer should only be resonsible for dispatching the "time elapsed" actions.

My other idea is to subscribe a listener to the store which will check the state and play the sound when necessary.

Comment: Your second plan sounds solid. That way you don't create side effects in your thunk.

Answer (score 1):

How about using a `sound` store like this:

```js
const initialState = {
  currentSound: undefined
}

export default function sound(state = initialState, action) {
  switch(action.type) {
    case UPDATE_TIME:
      const time = action.time
      const sounds = {
        6: '/sound1.mp3',
        22: '/sound2.mp3',
        99: '/sound3.mp3'
      }

      return Object.assign({}, state, {currentSound: sounds[time]})
  }
}
```

Then, in your component you can use `connect` from `react-redux` to get your state (`state.sound.currentSound`) and play the sound if there is one. Since the store will be updated every time the action is dispatched, if there is no sound for that time, `currentSound` will be `undefined`.